# Using HMSegmentedController indexPath in another method

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app I am using scrollable segment controller on header view of tableview and put dynamic data in it.

When click on segment index path, the particular id is get. Match this id with other entity data base change table view data.
My problem is, I cannot use segment index path in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

I am using different methods for this but it not work.

Comment: Can you add some code? how are you trying to solve?

Comment: - (BOOL)segmentedControlChangedValue:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {